# How do you access React statics within instance methods?

Tags: reactjs, static, constants, instance-methods

I'm using React 16.13.0.  I have defined this static block within my component ...

```
class FormContainer extends Component {
  statics: {
    DEFAULT_COUNTRY: 484;
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    ...

  componentDidMount() {
    let initialCountries = [];
    let initialProvinces = [];
    // Get initial countries
    fetch('/countries/')
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        }).then(data => {
        initialCountries = data.map((country) => {
            return country
        });
        console.log("output ...");
        console.log(initialCountries);
        this.setState({
            countries: initialCountries,
        });
    });
    // Get initial provinces (states)
    console.log("val:" + this.DEFAULT_COUNTRY);
```

My question is, how do I reference that static block?   The above

```
console.log("val:" + this.DEFAULT_COUNTRY);
```

produces

```
undefined
```

Comment: Are you expecting some kind of specific React feature here? You seem to just be defining the type of a public property in TypeScript syntax.

Comment: I would simply like to know how to access the value of the static variable.  If it has nothing to do with React, so much the better.

Comment: That's *not* a static variable, though, hence my question. I'm not sure where you got the idea that `statics: {...}` was the thing you wanted - could you share that?

Comment: Try with `public static DEFAULT_COUNTRY = 484;`

Comment: Thanks @johnannchopin, I probably should have mentioned this is a .jsx file.  Perhaps for that reason, when I try what you suggest, I get the compile error, " Parsing error: Unexpected token" and the compile error marker is pointing at the word "static."

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have access modifiers: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#public-private-and-protected-modifiers, and `static` may not be handled by your transpilation. It's still unclear where `statics:` came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confusion comes from old `React.createClass` function that you would use if your runtime didn't support classes as a Javascript feature. You would pass an object in React.createClass and React would create sort-of-a-class for that component. There, `statics` property on that object would serve like an object with all static properties of that pseudo class:

```
// old
const MyComponent = React.createClass({
  statics: {
    DEFAULT_COUNTRY: 484
  },
  render: function() {}
})
```

There is no real class going on here, it's just an object inside an object, and it is indeed easy to confuse with e.g. static block in Java

With ES6 classes (which you are using) static properties are declared like this

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  static DEFAULT_COUNTRY = 484
  static ANOTHER_STATIC_PROPERTY = 23

  render () {}
}
```

And can be accessed as `MyComponent.DEFAULT_COUNTRY` anywhere

You are most likely using Babel, in that case, [babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) should be enabled, as not all browsers support this feature. Node without Babel supports class properties from version 12

There are no static **blocks** in Javascript per se, but you can modify the class from static context from outside, e.g.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  static DEFAULT_COUNTRY = 484
  static ANOTHER_STATIC_PROPERTY = 23

  render () {}
}

MyComponent.HELLO = 'world'
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the declaration has an issue, you should use below code:

```
class FormContainer extends Component {
  statics = { // use equal sign not colon sign
    DEFAULT_COUNTRY: 484, // use comma here not semicolon
  };
```

Then in everywhere of `FormContainer` class, you can access by `this.statics`, for your default country you can access by `this.statics.DEFAULT_COUNTRY`.

By using the colon for declaring the `statics` variable of the class, you just get `undefined`.

**Hint**: do not use [`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) keyword. it defines a static variable for the class that is not accessible inside the class. in ReactJS the `static` keyword often use for declaring [prop types](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes) of class props members.

---

### Update

**To prove this correctness of code**: see the IDE and the Browser

1. [image: The code]
2. [image: The result]

If you got an error, please show your code, maybe you call it in an irrelevant place.

Comment: This just creates field called `statics` and has nothing to do with static fields. Big difference from static fields is that this object will be created every time new instance of a class is created. On contrary with static fields that are created only once when the program starts. Also, static variables are accessible from class with `MyClass.variableName`

Comment: Hi @AmerllicA, this doesn't work.  When I try "this.statics.DEFAULT_COUNTRY", I get the compile error, "TypeError: Cannot read property 'DEFAULT_COUNTRY' of undefined".

Comment: Dear @Max, Dave wanna use the variable inside the class, with `static` key defining it is just accessible just like you said. but here is the ReactJS environment. it is the true way.

Comment: Dear @Dave, please see the update, I think you still use colon `:` for declaring or you used a [`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) keyword. please just write like my screenshot. use `=` to declare **statics** and do not use [`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) keyword before the **statics**.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s use:

`static DEFAULT_COUNTRY = 484`

With `static` you can assign a property/method to the class function itself, not to its prototype. The value of this in `FormContainer.DEFAULT_COUNTRY` is the class constructor FormContainer itself.

You can access it from within the class as `this.constructor.DEFAULT_COUNTRY`. And as `FormContainer.DEFAULT_COUNTRY` within the class and out of it.
So, `console.log("val:" + this.constructor.DEFAULT_COUNTRY);`

Consider the following as an options to store DEFAULT_COUNTRY`:

```
class FormContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.DEFAULT_COUNTRY = 484;
  }
  render(){
    console.log(this.DEFAULT_COUNTRY)
    ...
  }
};
```

or

```
class FormContainer extends Component {
   DEFAULT_COUNTRY = 484;
   render(){
     console.log(this.DEFAULT_COUNTRY)
     ...
   }
};
```

or, this could be also an option:

```
class FormContainer extends Component {
  statics = {
    DEFAULT_COUNTRY: 484,
  };
  render(){
    console.log(this.statics.DEFAULT_COUNTRY)
     ...
  }
};
```

But in the last example, `statics` is not key word, but just a name of class field. Hope this will help you.